# Which Google API do I need to show a map & icon / marker

Tags: api, google-maps

I'm just starting out on a new website & want to add a Google map onto the page. (i already know the Geo code / location).

I did find a good tutorial, however all i'm getting is a message "Oops, something when wrong" message.

I have tried to go to developers.google.com & research this, but find DOZENS / a hundred different APIs for Google maps. & im unclear as to which API I need.

1) i know google has its own 'product forum' - but theres no forum for Google apis. & the support page directed me here...

2) all i want the map to do is

- i provide a geocode / location.
- it displays the map in the size / area I want
- allow the user to zoom in/out and move the map

Can someone advise me the 'latest' / 'recent' version, of a tutorial on how to achieve this.

https://developers.google.com/maps/get-started/

Ps I want the map to work on android / PC & other versions of browser a person may use. Do i need to create HTML code / access different  apis for each browser ? the above page has dozens of options.

Comment: sounds for me like a standard use-case of google maps. Take a look at the official doc´s there a several examples, that should nearly do everything you want. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/?hl=de

Comment: Thanks - the example looks like what im after...  Ive added it to my (test) site - but im still getting an 'oops' message. http://animals.kwister.com/view/2  I'll recheck line by line to see if im missing anything.  Is there a site we can go to - To put in a URL & it 'tests' the google map code & tells us which line is wrong (for google maps)

Answer (score 0):

FIXED it - I went to the console screen that generates the API key, & checked / confirmed my key.

I found the problem that my domain name was missing a character / letter - i edited it & the map now works